# Sms application - List_item error

Tags: java, android, xml

Hello i have a problem with this aplication.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Smsfive extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created.
* @param messages */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, ListView messages) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
List<String> msgList = getSMS();

for(int i = 0; i<msgList.size(); i++) {
System.out.println(msgList.get(i));
}
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.list, msgList);  --> there is error with list_item

//ListView messages;
messages.setAdapter(adapter);
messages.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
long arg3) {
SmsManager m = SmsManager.getDefault();
TextView view;
String destinationNumber=(String) ((TextView) view).getText();
m.sendTextMessage(destinationNumber, null, destinationNumber, null, null);

}
});
}

public List<String> getSMS() {
List<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
Cursor c = null;
try{
c = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query (uri, null, null ,null,null);
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
try{
for (boolean hasData = c.moveToFirst(); hasData; hasData = c.moveToNext()) {
final String address = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address"));
final String body = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
messages.add("Number: " + address + ". Message: " + body);
}
}catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
c.close();
return messages;
}
}
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/widget30"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
androidrientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<ListView
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Error:

> Description Resource Path Location
>   Type list_item cannot be resolved or
>   is not a field Smsfive.java
>   /Sms5/src/sms/five line 30 Java
>   Problem

What can i do please?

Comment: I'm assuming the XML file you showed us is named `list_item.xml` ?

Comment: Please do not post the same question multiple times.

Comment: Wow - rather pissed I answered a question you asked twice in 8 minutes.  and you haven't bothered to accept either my answer or the correct answer in your other question either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely either you are missing name of the file or even file `list_item.xml`. So Insure that this layout file must be exist in your `res/layout` directory.

Comment: Yes,thank you.But there is another problem :( if i open that project,there is no action.Can somebody tell me where is the problem? i am trying to create  sms app witch shows me Sms inbox in listview.

Comment: **Which project and what action?**

Comment: I have written sms app (Smsfive).If i open this aplication (Smsfive) i can see only black screen with name of aplication.I want to create aplication witch shows me Sms inbox in ListView.Can you help me please? Source code is above.Thank you..

Answer (score 1):

You are not including the correct R file.  When you create a resource, like list_item, an identifier for it is added to the generated R file.  This R file is located in the package of your application.  There is also an Android R file, which is in a different package.

Make sure you have an import statement the imports the correct R file.

Comment: thank you but i have another problem :( if i open this aplication i can see only black screen with name of my aplication.Can you check my source code and tell me where is the problem? thank you.Sorry for my english :( i am czech..

Comment: @Adam - open a new question if you have a new problem.

Answer (score 1):

What is the name of your xml file?  (Hint: it has to be list_item for R.layout.list_item to work)

Comment: Yes thank you, but i have another problem.if i open this aplication i can see only black screen with name of my aplication.I am trying to create aplication witch shows me SMS inbox in ListView.Can you check my source code and tell me where is the problem? thank you.

Comment: Since the original problem has been fixed, you should accept my answer as the solution and then ask another question.  Piggybacking questions will not produce the result you desire.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this:

```
setContentView(R.layout.list_item);

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, msgList);
```

What you are probably trying to do is have a custom `TextView` in your `ListView` but it won't work like this.

Comment: Yes thanks.But if i open this app i can see only black screen with name of my aplication.I am trying to create aplication witch shows me Sms Inbox in listview.Can you check my source code and tell me where is the problem :(? than you